# Swing Threads: Event dispatch Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am having some major problems with swing's Thread model at the moment. AFAIK Swing defines 3 different Threads:

- initial Threads: Here the program starts aka main methods, where the GUI will be started with some init() methods
- Event dispatch Thread: The main thread for the GUI. Every bit of initialization of the GUI, updating the GUI etc. belongs here in this single thread
- Worker Thread: for some background stuff of heavy weight tasks

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // init gui here
    }
});
}
```

This is a simple example in where the main method is the initial Thread, where the program starts and we invoke a new Thread (the Event dispatch Thread) where our GUI will be started.

Is this correct?

Now to my problem:

I am writing a Swing program, that connects to two different servers and visually dif's them. Therefore i have 2x Connection connection = ...
The first connection object to the "left" server exists within the initial main Thread, because the program will be executed within the environment of one of the servers => connection object is predefined by the environment and exists and the start of main(). The second connection object will be built manually within the program.

The problem now is that i use invokeLater() to shift every bit of GUI code to the Event dispatch Thread. Because i use a GUI to let the User select the credentials for the 2nd Server the connection code for the "right" server lies within the GUI and therefore in the Event dispatch Thread. However i do need both connection objects in one Thread because at one point i have to work with both objects at the same time.

Example:

```
public void run() {
// Left connection object is predefined and named "contect" here

// Right connection objects is created here using a GUI
connection = new ConnectionDialog().getConnection();

Project[] projects = connection.getProjects();
ProjectDialog pd = new ProjectDialog(Diff.this, projects);
otherProject = pd.getSelectedProject();
if (otherProject == null) {
    return;
}

this.leftStore = (TemplateStoreRoot) context.requireSpecialist(StoreAgent.TYPE).getStore(Store.Type.TEMPLATESTORE);
this.rightStore = otherProject.getUserService().getTemplateStore();
this.leftSets = context.requireSpecialist(ProjectAgent.TYPE).getTemplateSets();
this.rightSets = otherProject.getUserService().getProject().getTemplateSets();
this.init();
this.setEnabled(true);
this.setVisible(true);
}
```

What the hell can i do to make this work? Am i doing it wrong by shifting every GUI code to the event dispatch Thread? The docu says i have to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: I would not say "three".  There's the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), and there's all other threads.  The EDT  is the _only_ thread that can safely update the display.  Other threads can register event handlers and call `invokeLater(...)`, but if a non-EDT thread makes any other Swing method call, it likely will break your application.

Answer (score 0):

You must be creating a Frame to hold your UI right? Subclass JFrame, add your own constructor and pass the first connection object as a parameter. You can save it in your frame object and use it within it.

That said, you are not expected to do any lengthy calculations, waiting for network data etc. in the UI thread, if you want your UI to be responsive.

Comment: Yes and yes. I am not doing any lengthy calculations, i just shifted all my GUI code to this extern thread (Event dispatch Thread). Yes, i do my GUI with a JFrame as a super container, but i don't think i need to extend JFrame. As far as i know just passing a final variable to the new thread is sufficient, which is what i am doing!

Comment: So my workflow atm is:
1. start the program, generate the 1st connection object in the initial thread
2. start up invokeLater() and do my gui stuff inside the extra thread after passing in final connection to that new thread
3. connect within the gui code (since the connectiondialog is gui itself) to the 2nd connection obj
4. do some stuff with both connection objects and initialize the differ with them

-- Break between 3 and 4 with "all modules ignored" in javax, which has to be a thread problem i suppose